# Jest Unit Test for TypeScript Class in Node.js is not covering test coverage for most of the part

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, jestjs

Please find my node js code and respective unit test. 
but test coverage shows from obs.pipe all the line are not covered.
Please advise on unit test to cover entire code.

This is RxJSUtilsService class in TypeScript

```
@Injectable()
export class RxJSUtilsService {
  genericRetryStrategy(
    options: GenericRetryOptions = {
      maxRetryAttempts: 3,
      scalingDuration: 1000,
      excludedStatusCodes: [],
    },
  ): (obs: Observable<any>) => Observable<any> {
    return (obs: Observable<any>) =>
      obs.pipe(
        mergeMap((error, i: number) => {
          i++;
          if (
            i > options.maxRetryAttempts ||
            options.excludedStatusCodes.find(e => e === error.status)
          ) {
            return throwError(error);
          }
          return timer(i * options.scalingDuration);
        }),
      );
  }
}
```

This is unit Test code. test coverage is not covered and shows from obs.pipe all the line are not covered.

```
describe('RxjsUtilsService', () => {
  let rxJSUtilsService: RxJSUtilsService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [RxJSUtilsService],
    }).compile();

    rxJSUtilsService = module.get<RxJSUtilsService>(RxJSUtilsService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(rxJSUtilsService).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('GenericRetryStrategy should be called', () => {
    const source = interval(100);
    jest.spyOn(rxJSUtilsService, 'genericRetryStrategy');
    source
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(val => {
          return val < 2 ? throwError('divisible by six') : of(val);
        }),
        retryWhen(
          rxJSUtilsService.genericRetryStrategy({
            maxRetryAttempts: 10,
            scalingDuration: 1000,
          }),
        ),
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: val => {
          expect(rxJSUtilsService.genericRetryStrategy).toBeCalled();
        },
      });
  });

  it('GenericRetryStrategy should throw error', () => {
    const source = interval(100);
    jest.spyOn(rxJSUtilsService, 'genericRetryStrategy');
    source
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(val => {
          return val > 0 ? throwError('divisible by six') : of(val);
        }),
        retryWhen(
          rxJSUtilsService.genericRetryStrategy({
            maxRetryAttempts: 2,
            scalingDuration: 1000,
          }),
        ),
      )
      .subscribe({
        error: err => {
          expect(rxJSUtilsService.genericRetryStrategy).toBeCalled();
        },
      });
  });
});
```